# How to create a server certificate from a letsencrypt.org certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, letsencrypt

I have created a letscrypt.org certificate using `letsencrypt run` which works fine as a SSL certificate on `apache2`. How can I create another server certificate signed (and thus trusted) by the letsencrypt.org certificate?

I tried to create a CSR with

```
openssl req -new -key file.key -out file.csr
```

which I assume I can sign with

```
openssl x509 -extensions server_cert -req -in file.csr -CA /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain name]/fullchain.pem -CAkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain name]/privkey.pem -CAcreateserial -out file.pem -days 500 -sha256
```

The result is the `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` in `firefox` 47.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I assume the resulting certificate is trusted like the letsencrypt.org certificate is since the chain of trust shouldn't be broken. The to be created certificate is unnecessary. I want to create it for the purpose of learning in case this question doesn't reveal I'm requesting something impossible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to create a mutual trust between servers, for instance, you can do that with self-signed certificates and explicitly importing them into truststores on each side.  If you want publicly trusted certificates, you need to get a letsencrypt cert for each server and use those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use your SSL certificate purchased from Let's Encrypt to sign other certificates. In order to do this, your certificate must be CA certificate. This is done by setting `isCA=true` in the `BasicConstraints` certificate extension. In addition, `KeyUsages` extension should include a `keyCertSign` bit enabled.

More information on how Basic Constraints extension works in my blog post: [Basic Constraints certificate extension](https://www.pkisolutions.com/basic-constraints-certificate-extension/)

Your SSL certificate doesn't have such setting and no one will give you such.

What you need is to acquire another certificate from CA  provider (Let's Encrypt, for instance).

Edit:
as aside note. You can purchase CA certificate from public CAs, however it is quite expensive. Service costs are thousands and thousands dollars. In addition, you will have to purchase a Hardware Security Module (HSM) which are quite expensive ($5k+ for PCI card and around $30k+ for net HSM like Thales nCipher). And you will have to pass external audits to verify policy conformance. This procedure is called Certification Authority Root Signing. I wrote an article about the subject: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5973.certification-authority-root-signing.aspx

I suspect that this is not your case, so as @crovers suggested, you just need to acquire another certificate from Let's Encrypt like you already did for your domain.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! Do you think/know if there's way to do that with `certbot` or another letsencrypt.org client? I don't find any option in `man letsencrypt` and only blog/diary-like articles like https://letsencrypt.org/2015/06/04/isrg-ca-certs.html on [google](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=letsencrypt+ca+certificate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=T8aPV_D1KJHZ8AeDsYkY) which don't explain whether or not I can get a CA certificate.

Comment: You cannot get a CA certificate. It is for CAs. You can generate another DV certificate from Let's Encrypt just like you did before to secure another domain if you want.

Comment: @void_in, actually you can (under certain circumstances, see my edits), but not in this case (I think so).